# Code only saving last polyline with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile

My shapefile contains multiple polylines to segment and buffer and save in a new shapefile. My ArcPy code only saves the last polyline.

How do I save each output?

```
def main():
import arcpy

fc = r'D:\tayyab\New folder\buffer\cut_buffers\line.shp'
fc_out = r'D:\tayyab\New folder\buffer\cut_buffers\buffers_v11'
length_section = 100.0 # each 100 meters
buffer_dist = 10.0
tol_dist = 0.1 #
sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference

# get polyline (first one from fc)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, 'SHAPE@')as cursor:       
    for row in cursor:
        polyline = row[0]
        lst_buffers = []
        start = 0
        end = length_section
        print "polyline.length", polyline.length
        while start < polyline.length:
            segment = polyline.segmentAlongLine(start, end, False)
            buffer1 = segment.buffer(buffer_dist)

            if end > polyline.length:
                end = polyline.length
            print " - start", start, "  end", end

            # get points around start and end of segment to determine angles
            pntg_d1, pntg_d2, pntg_start = getPoints(polyline, start, tol_dist)
            pntg_d3, pntg_d4, pntg_end = getPoints(polyline, end, tol_dist)
            pntg_center = polyline.positionAlongLine((start + end) / 2.0, False)

            # angle at start and end of segment
            angle_start = getAngle(pntg_d1, pntg_d2)
            angle_end = getAngle(pntg_d3, pntg_d4)

            # create perpendicular cutline
            cut_line_start = createPerpendicularCutLine(pntg_start, angle_start, buffer_dist, sr)
            cut_line_end = createPerpendicularCutLine(pntg_end, angle_end, buffer_dist, sr)

            # cut buffer polygon
            polygon = cutPolygonWithLines(buffer1, [cut_line_start, cut_line_end], pntg_center)
            lst_buffers.append(polygon)

            # for next segment
            start = end
            end += length_section

        # store results
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lst_buffers, fc_out)


def cutPolygonWithLines(polygon, lst_lines, pntg_center):
    for line in lst_lines:
        try:
            lst_pols = polygon.cut(line)
        except:
            lst_pols = [polygon]
        polygon = getCorrectPolygon(lst_pols, pntg_center)
    return polygon


def getCorrectPolygon(lst_pols, pntg_center):
    correct_polygon = None
    for polygon in lst_pols:
        if polygon.contains(pntg_center):
            correct_polygon = polygon
            break
    return correct_polygon


def getPoints(polyline, dist, tolerance):
    d1 = dist - tolerance if dist - tolerance > 0 else 0
    d2 = dist + tolerance if dist + tolerance < polyline.length else polyline.length
    pntg_d1 = polyline.positionAlongLine(d1, False)
    pntg_d2 = polyline.positionAlongLine(d2, False)
    pntg_dist = polyline.positionAlongLine(dist, False)
    return pntg_d1, pntg_d2, pntg_dist


def getAngle(pntg1, pntg2):
    return pntg1.angleAndDistanceTo(pntg2, method='PLANAR')[0]


def createPerpendicularCutLine(pntg, angle, dist, sr):
    pntg_cut_1 = pntg.pointFromAngleAndDistance(angle - 90, dist * 2.0, 'PLANAR')
    pntg_cut_2 = pntg.pointFromAngleAndDistance(angle + 90, dist * 2.0, 'PLANAR')
    cut_line = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([pntg_cut_1.firstPoint, pntg_cut_2.firstPoint]), sr)
    return cut_line


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your problem is you're exporting to fc_out on every iteration using copy features which will overwrite *everything in that feature class* with the new line, hence you only see the last line. Use append https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000 if the fc_out already exists https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000069000000 to add your line to the existing contents of fc_out .